# Cant commit in git bash using atom on Windows

Tags: git, atom-editor

I am trying to set up Atom as my default text editor in git bash.

however, I cant get the git commit command to execute..

I have used "git config --global core.editor "atom" to get this error:
[image]

If I use " git config --global core.editor "atom --wait", then the error is about the powershell.
[image]

In either case, Atom opens up ok, however I dont have a chance to write any changes
before the Aborting commit message appears in bash, like here.
[image]

My environmental path variable is set up ok (C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\atom\bin)

Not sure what else to check?  I am on Windows 7.  any advice?

so far, I'm getting by using  git commit -m "my change" to circumvent this problem - yet I wish I could use Atom.

Comment: Do `git commit -m "my message"` as an alternative and that should work.

Comment: yes, thats what I am using.. I'm frustrated I cant fix it otherwise

Comment: Unfortunately you are not. All screen shots show "git commit" and not "git commit -m "message"`

Comment: you see, my course advises me to use -m ".." as an alternative  option. so  I was aware of that. I had to share the screenshots of my problems with Atom.

Comment: Curious. I had the impression that `atom --wait` worked in all cases. It looks as though your setup wants you to install Powershell, but that seems like excess to me. There's also an open issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/20152), and several maybe-duplicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58218086/1256452).

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I just ran the following line of code in the Windows command prompt and it got resolved:

```
git config --global core.editor "atom -w -d"
```